# Why application name doesn't show under the icon?

Tags: android, android-manifest

I've just published a new app in google play and the name of the app is no under its icon when it is installed on a device. i can't figure out why. Have you ever heard about this problem and its ppossible solution?

Comment: does it have an name when you install it through adb?

Comment: Please post your manifest

Comment: no, in the emulator it has the same problem

Comment: make sure android:label="@string/app_name" is under your <application> tag in your Android manifest